# sql максимальное количество записей по группам

Tags: sql, access

Есть таблица типа:

```
Год  \ Имя
1948 \ Татьяна
1948 \ Наталья
1948 \ Татьяна
1949 \ Татьяна
1949 \ Наталья
1949 \ Ольга
1949 \ Ольга
```

Нужно получить самое распространённое имя за каждый год. Т.е. результат:

```
1948 \ Татьяна
1949 \ Ольга
```

```
SELECT top 1 Year(ДатаРожд) as Год, Имя, Count(Имя)
FROM Лист
where Year(ДатаРожд)=1948
group by Year(ДатаРожд), Имя
order by Count(Имя) desc;
```

Данный код подходит для того, чтобы выделить одно имя за каждый год, если каждый отдельный год вручную прописать. А списком я не могу понять как сделать. Подскажите пжлст!

Comment: Коррелированный агрегирующий подзапрос в списке вывода.

Comment: за что вы так со мной? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Усовершенствовал код.
Теперь выполняется за 6 секунд, вместо 25 минут.

```
   select year(ДатаРожд) as god, (
            select top 1 Имя
            from Лист
            where year(ДатаРожд)=year(list2.ДатаРожд) and Пол='ЖЕНСКИЙ'
            group by year(ДатаРожд), Имя
            order by count(Имя) desc
            ) as Name
    from Лист as list2
    group by year(ДатаРожд)
    order by year(ДатаРожд)
```

Distinct нельзя было использовать, до меня потом дошло.

Answer (score 0):

В Mysql возможен такой порядок действий :

```
    SELECT year, name, COUNT(name) AS ca
    FROM list
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Это создана таблица, считающая кол-во имён по годам, к которой будем обращаться в подзапросе,выбирая MAX. Ей потребуется алиас, например, q.
Весь запрос:

```
    SELECT year,name
    FROM list
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING COUNT(name)=(
    SELECT MAX(ca) FROM (
    SELECT year, name, COUNT(name) AS ca
    FROM list
    GROUP BY 1,2)q
    );
```

Comment: В ACCESS ругается "Ваш запрос не содержит указанное выражение "year" как часть агрегатной функции"

Comment: Аа, у Вас по-русски написано название столбца. Значит, год вместо year. У меня запрос рсботает, я создала подобные таблички и проверила.

Comment: Вы извините, но у меня в Access не работает.
В MS SQL Server выдаёт: "Каждое выражение GROUP BY должно содержать по меньшей мере один столбец, который не является внешней ссылкой."
Поэтому я изучил тему, написал запрос сам, но получился слишком медленный запрос. Если можете подсказать, что с ним не так, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Изучил коррелированный агрегирующий подзапрос.
Но в MS Access он всё равно не работает. Запустил в MS SQL Server Management Studio. В моей базе почти 200 тыс. записей. Запрос выполняется полчаса. Раньше я такого долгого выполнения не встречал. Возможно, данный запрос можно и нужно оптимизировать.

```
select distinct year(ДатаРожд) as god, (
        select top 1 Имя
        from Лист
        where year(ДатаРожд)=year(list2.ДатаРожд)
        group by year(ДатаРожд), Имя
        order by count(Имя) desc
        ) as Name
from Лист as list2
order by year(ДатаРожд)
```

Кому интересно, это я по одному российскому городу провёл исследование, просто ради интереса. Самые распространённые имена по годам рождения выглядят так (делал 2 раза запрос с выборкой по полу):
[image: Самые распространённые имена по году рождения]